# Hiding columns in Excel based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to hide certain columns in my Excel sheet (called "Template account") based on a value from a picklist that is selected in cell AC5.

The logic is as follows:

1) If the picklist value in cell AC5 is "Energy and Resources" then I'd like the columns BJ:BO to be hidden.

2) If the picklist value in cell AC5 is "Defence" then I'd like the columns BP:CA to be hidden and so on..

3) Else if AC5 contains none of the picklist values in AC5 then don't hide anything

The code I attempted looks like this, however it does not work. Can someone please provide me with some input?

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim cellvalue As String
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Set ws = Sheet("Template account")

If cellvalue Like "*Energy and Resources*" Then
Columns("BJ:BO").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
If cellvalue Like "*Defence*" Then
Columns("BP:CA").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Else
Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You never use `Target`. I think you'll just need to replace `cellvalue`  with `Target.Value`  and it should work.  You may want to qualify the `Columns` with `ws.Columns(...` as well.

Comment: I doubt your code even compiles. I'd expect VBA to complain about a missing `End If` here (did you mean to use `ElseIf` instead of `Else {newline} If`?). Also the last `Else` block is redundant, and `cellValue` is used before it's assigned anything, so it's always going to be an empty string, so none of the conditions can ever work. `Sheets` should be `Worksheets`, and `Columns` is implicitly referring to the active sheet, you might want to use or at least compare to `Target.Parent` instead, to be sure you're working on the correct worksheet.

Answer (score 2):

to detect a change in a cell value you must use `Worksheet_Change()` event handler

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address(False, False) = "AC5" Then '<-- check for changed cell to be in AC5
        Select Case Target.Value '<-- act correspondingly to changed cell value
            Case "Energy and Resources"
                Columns("BJ:BO").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Case "Defence"
                Columns("BP:CA").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Case "...."
                ' go on with other cases
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

should you want to unhide columns BJ:BO and BP:CA when neither "Energy and Resources" nor "Defence" is the value of the changed pickup cell, then the code slightly changes in the last part of the `Select Case` block

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address(False, False) = "AC5" Then '<-- check for changed cell to be in AC5
        Select Case Target.Value '<-- act correspondingly to changed cell value
            Case "Energy and Resources"
                Columns("BJ:BO").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Case "Defence"
                Columns("BP:CA").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Case Else
                Union(Columns("BJ:BO"), Columns("BP:CA")).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Your second example might be better written as `...Then` `Columns("BJ:BO").EntireColumn.Hidden = Target.Value = "Energy and Resources"` `Columns("BP:CA").EntireColumn.Hidden = Target.Value = "Defence"` `End If ...` - that will ensure the "Defence" columns are visible when "Energy and Resources" is selected and vice-versa.  At the moment both sets of columns could end up being hidden.  (But maybe that is what the OP wants?  It seems strange to be **hiding** one of multiple blocks of data - it's more common to be making one block visible while hiding all the rest.)

Comment: Hi thank you for your suggestions! Is there a way I can get the columns to 'unhide' on deleting the value in cell AC5? Currently if I enter a value in AC5 then certain columns are hidden. If I enter a different value in AC5, the previously hidden columns remain hidden along with the newly hidden ones.

Comment: you are welcome. Without getting thoroughly what you asked for yet I can answer: "yes, it's possible", but you'd better give complete detail of the expected behavior upon different AC5 cell editing

Comment: @Morpheus, did you get through it?

Answer (score 1):

Place your code under the `Workbook_SheetChange`. Currently the event you are under will only trigger when you select different cell not when actual changes are happening in cells. Also as @BruceWayne states you never pass the value of cell AC5 to your `cellvalue` variable. Code with some changes:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Sh.Name = "Template account" And Target.Address = "$AC:$5" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim cellvalue As String
        cellvalue = Target.Value2

        If cellvalue Like "*Energy and Resources*" Then
            Sh.Columns("BJ:BO").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        ElseIf cellvalue Like "*Defence*" Then
            Sh.Columns("BP:CA").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Else
            Sh.Columns("BJ:BO").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            Sh.Columns("BP:CA").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Added a check to confirm changes are on the correct sheet and cell. Disabled events while code is running so hiding the columns doesn't trigger the event again. Enabled at the end. Added showing the columns again on the `Else`. Have not tested.

Comment: 1) Hiding columns doesn't trigger a sheet change event. moreover since both picklist cell and columns to be hidden/revealed are in "Template account" worksheet then it isn't necessary to use a Workbook scoped event handler and it suffices to write a worksheet one in the relevant worksheet code pane. 2) `Target.Address = "$AC:$5` must be `Target.Address = "$AC$5` 3)`cellvalue Like "*Energy and Resources*"` (and the likes) doesn't correspond to OP's narrative _"If the picklist value in cell AC5 is "Energy and Resources" "_